# Intersection between polylines feature to polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, line

I would like to transform a line shapefile into polygons. However, the tool Vector>Geometry>Line to Polygon doesn'to work to me. What I would like to do is using the intersection between lines and make them as vertices of a polygon.
In ArcGis, the tool Feature to Polygon does exactly what I want.
Does someone know a way of doing so in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS, it works only when both layers share the same CRS. If you switch `On-the-fly-reprojection` **OFF**, they should still align.

If not, save one of the layers to another name and the CRS of the other, add that to the canvas, delete the first layer, and the intersection will work.